# Javascript: how to remove last comma in for-loop

Tags: javascript

How can I remove the last comma from this function.

```
   for(var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) { 
          if(i % 2 === 0) { 
            div.innerHTML += l + ","; 
          } 
         else { 
            div.innerHTML += " ";
         }
   }
```

Comment: Add this after the for loop, `dividedThree.innerHTML = dividedThree.innerHTML.substring(0, dividedThree.innerHTML.length - 1);`

Comment: `if (i % 2 === 0 && i !== 100) { ...` ?

Comment: in practice, you should avoid updating innerHTML in a loop like that

Comment: do you really add `l`? or is it `i`? with `i` you get `0, 2, 4, 6, ..., 98, 100,`. the function is missing some `()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, use arrays instead strings for sum strings, its faster.
Second:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0 ;i <= 100; i+=2) arr.push(l);
dividedThree.innerHTML = arr.join(', ');
```

Comment: in the original code, it's the lower case letter L, and it is only added every second iteration

Comment: `i <= 100` ... the original result has 51 * `l`, not 50 :p

Answer (score 0):

Try using `and (&&)` condition for 100 and show only `i` value for 100.

```js
function loop() {
  var dividedThree = document.getElementById('MY_ID');
  for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0 && i !== 100) {
      dividedThree.innerHTML += i + ", ";
    } else if (i === 100) {
      dividedThree.innerHTML += i;
    } else {
      dividedThree.innerHTML += " ";
    }
  }
}
loop();
```

```html
<p id="MY_ID">
  <p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function loop {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            dividedThree.innerHTML += l;
            if (i < 100)
            {
                dividedThree.innerHTML += ",";
            }
        } else {
            dividedThree.innerHTML += " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

does this version work for you?

```
function loop() {
    var data = '';
    for (var i = 0; i <= 49; i++) { 
        data  += l + ',' + ' ';
    }
    data  += l;
    dividedThree.innerHTML = data;
}
```

What are you trying to do? where does 'l' come from?